# Do I abuse notation ? $\mu(dx)=f(x)dx=f(g(t))g'(t)dt=\mu(dt)$?

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, coordinate-systems

I have that $$\mu(A)=\int_A f(x)dx=\int_B f(g(t))g'(t)dt.$$

Do I abuse notation when I right $$\mu(dx)=f(x)dx=f(g(t))g'(t)dt=\mu(dt) \ \ ?$$

---

In fact in an exercise of physic I have that $dF=F(x)dx$. Since $$F=\int F(x)dx=\int g(\theta )rd\theta , $$

we get $$dF=g(\theta )rd\theta.$$

I'm a bit confuse. Shouldn't it be $$dF(x)=F(x)dx=g(\theta )rd\theta =dF(t) \ \ ?$$

Could someone explain what we do ? (I can accept it in some way, but I would like to understand better).

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that $\int f(x)d\mu(x) =\int f(t)d\mu(t)$ you cannot write $d\mu(x) =d\mu(t)$.

Comment: So my exercise (in physique) is not correct ? (it's not an abuse notation)

Comment: Well, I am unfamiliar with some of the notations that physicists use but in Mathematics the equations you have written are not acceptable.

Comment: If $F:M\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a manifold, then we write $dF(x)=f(x)dx$ in $(x,\varphi )$ and in an other charts, $(t,\psi )$ we'll write $F(t)=f(g(t))g'(t)dt$. This is commonly made, right ?

Comment: @user657324 Yes, you are right.

Comment: I guess that $g$ is a coordinate change, and "abuse notation" mean that if $dF(x)=F(x)dx$, we write $dF(t)=F(g(t))g'(t)dt$  in the coordinate $t$, don't you think so ? And for the meaure, it should be $\mu(dx)=F(x)dx=F(g'(t))g(t)=\mu(g^{-1}(t))$, no ?